# Check if combobox is opened

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

How can I check if the combobox's dropdown list is opened? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboBox?view=winrt-19041)

Comment: [DropDownOpened](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.dropdownopened?view=winrt-19041)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe the [DropDownOpened](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.dropdownopened?view=winrt-19041) event which will be triggered when you try to open the dropdown list or use [IsDropDownOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.isdropdownopen?view=winrt-19041) property to judge whether the drop-down portion of the ComboBox is currently open.

.xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" DropDownOpened="MyComboBox_DropDownOpened">
    <ComboBoxItem>123</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

.cpp:

```
void AppCX::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    bool isOpen = MyComboBox->IsDropDownOpen;
}


void AppCX::MainPage::MyComboBox_DropDownOpened(Platform::Object^ sender, Platform::Object^ e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IsDropDownOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.isdropdownopen?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ComboBox_IsDropDownOpen)  property.

```
Definition

Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the drop-down portion of the ComboBox is currently open.
```